# Returning empty list -1

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def findMiniRow(numlst):
    x = []
    for lst in numlst:
        x.append(sum(lst))
        m = min(x)
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == m]
```

output:

```
>>> findMiniRow([])
[]
>>> findMiniRow([[3.99,-12.5,8.61],[0],[-3,-5,-7]])
[2]
>>> findMiniRow([[1,2,3],[-100],[10,-30.5,8]])
[1]
>>> findMiniRow([[10,20],[100,200],[8,7,6,5],[13],[8,9,10]])
[3]
>>>
```

When findMiniRow([]) I want the output to be -1. I tried a If != []/ Else return -1 but couldn't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this special case is right up-front:

```
def findMiniRow(numlst):
    if not numlst:
        return -1
    x = []
    for lst in numlst:
        x.append(sum(lst))
        m = min(x)
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == m]
```

Or, if you really want to use a ternary at the end:

```
def findMiniRow(numlst):
    x = []
    for lst in numlst:
        x.append(sum(lst))
        m = min(x)
    return [i for i, j in enumerate(x) if j == m] if numlst else -1
```

but then you're creating `x` for nothing!